# Localstorage troubles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to create a webapp, which you will click in a button, and his ID is saved to the localstorage, and change the style.
But when I save in localstorage, the last button that i have click, replace the button´s ID before it.
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function(){
        $("li a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem('ativo', $(this).html())
    });

    var ativo = localStorage.getItem('ativo');

    $("li a").each(function(index){
        if($(this).html() == ativo) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Your `click` handler runs every time you click on something.  The other lines, the `localStorage.getItem` and the `$("li a").each`, only run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is a key-value store. By setting a key, you replace the value of that key if it is already set. However, you could store a stringified array in localStorage, then retrieve it and add to it when needed.

```
//Store an array in local storage
localStorage.setItem('arr',JSON.stringify([6,8,9])

//retrieve the array, add to it, then save it again
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('arr'));
arr.push(23)
localStorage.setItem('arr', arr)
```