# Localstorage: Save multiple session's checkbox status without overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, checkbox, local-storage

What I want to do is for the status of the checkbox be saved into localstorage when user click "submit" without overwriting the previous status. So the localstorage might have values like "true, false, false, true..." etc. At the moment my localstorage will overwrites the status of the checkbox if I submit the form in a new session.

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
        document.getElementById("xbutton").addEventListener("click",savecheck,false); }
function savecheck(){
    var checkb = document.getElementById("MedA");
    localStorage.setItem("MedA", checkb.checked);
}
```

html:

```
<form>
        <div id='medA'>
            <input type="checkbox" id="MedA" name="Med" value="A">Medication A
         </div>
<input id="xbutton" type="button" onClick="savecheck()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: so use an array

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715948/localstorage-troubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
function savecheck() {
    var checkb = document.getElementById("MedA");
    var medAHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MedA') || "[]");
    medAHistory.push(checkb.checked);
    localStorage.setItem("MedA", JSON.stringify(medAHistory));
}
```

The thing to remember is that localStorage can only store string values.
That means, you need to serialize any object or array into a string when storing to localStorage, and then deserialize (parse) it when reading it back from localStorage.

Note: if you already saved the "MedA" item in local storage before, you need to remove it if you're changing its (parsed) representation from a simple value to an array.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering why does it gives double status everytime? Like if I uncheck the button and click submit, the value will be [false, false], even if I only clicked submit once?

Comment: the code works by saving multiple checkbox status, but it just keeps saving duplicate status for each form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
function savecheck() {
  var data = [];
  data[0] = document.getElementById("MedA").checked;
  localStorage.setItem("MedA", JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current localstorage item:

```
var oldItem = localStorage.getItem("MedA");
var newItem = oldItem +", " + String(checkb.checked);
localStorage.setItem(newItem, checkb.checked);
```

And maybe oput it a little bit more logic that deals with handling the commas (no comma if the original local storage variable was empty, for example).